How to apply different properties with different code
I am trying to set connecting to mongoDB with different profiles.
I have application.yml, application-dev.yml, application-op.yml, application-qa.yml, and application-st.yml.
And I want to apply all the properties differently.
For example,
I want to apply my MongoDBsource.java class to application.yml
settings.applyConnectionString(
        new ConnectionString(String.format("mongodb://%s:%d", host, port)));

But with all the other properties, I want to apply with this code.
settings.applyConnectionString(
        new ConnectionString(String.format("mongodb://%s:%d/?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false", host, port)));

How can I apply this?
I tried @Profile("dev") annotation.

I'd just use property substitutions in the yaml files to achieve this. You could have a mongodb.urlSuffix which defaults to empty string
application.yaml
mongodb:
  host: localhost
  port: 5000
  urlSuffix: ''
  url: mongodb://${mongodb.host}:${mongodb.port}${mongodb.urlSuffix}

application-dev.yaml
mongodb:
  urlSuffix: ?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false

application-op.yaml
mongodb:
  urlSuffix: ?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false

Then
@Component
public class MyFantasticService {
   private final MongoSettings settings;

   public MyFantasticService(@Value("${mongodb.url}") String mongoUrl) {
      settings = new MongoSettings();
      settings.applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(mongoUrl)));
      ...
   }
}


Use the value annotation to create a class variable then initisalise the connection with that.
Something like:
@Value
private String mongoDb;

settings.applyConnectionString(
            new ConnectionString(String.format(mongoDb, host, port)));

Your application.properties would then specify the value. Use application-dev.properties etc to specify different profiles.
To set the profile use:
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar


Here is an example of profile usage with Spring
Test Code
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
@ActiveProfiles({"test", "test-integration"})

These annotations specify that the test code should run with the “test” and “test-integration” profiles active.
Here is an example of profile usage with code:
Production Code
@Profile({"local", "test"})

This bean will be active for the “local” and “test” profiles.
@Profile({"!local & !test"}) 

This bean will be active for all profiles except “local” and “test”.
@Profile({"!test"})

This bean will be active for all profiles except “test”.
